# CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine pauses all actions when playing an effect

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, simpleaudioengine

I have implemented audio in my project, when initiating my own Sprite class in `create()` function with this code:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->getInstance()->preloadEffect("fx/frog.wav");
```

and when the sprite class is playing the effect with this code:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->getInstance()->playEffect("fx/frog.wav");
```

the backgound stops scrolling and other sprites stop moving until the sound effect ends.
I need your help please, I'm working with cocos2d-x-3.3 beta, and targeting WIN32 project.

Debug Output if needed:

```
Ready for GLSL
Ready for OpenGL 2.0
OpenGL error 0x0500 in ..\base\CCConfiguration.cpp cocos2d::Configuration::gatherGPUInfo 142


{
    gl.version: 3.2.9756 Compatibility Profile Context
    gl.supports_NPOT: true
    cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 3.3beta0
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
    cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
    gl.max_texture_size: 16384
    gl.vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
    gl.renderer: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
    gl.max_texture_units: 32
    gl.supports_ETC1: false
    gl.supports_S3TC: true
    gl.supports_ATITC: false
    gl.supports_PVRTC: false
    gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
    gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: false
    gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
}


AppDelegate : sd resolution
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MMDevAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wdmaud.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AudioSes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\midimap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mciwave.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0xc90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HangingSpider.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x920 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1924 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1ba0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1504 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc30 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1bf0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x16e4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1354 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x10b0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[4276] HangingSpider.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```